# How to referre to Android drawable login icon in a option menu XML?

Tags: android

I would like to use the built in Android drawable icon in my option menu. I am using Android 2.2., Eclipse 3.6.2.

In the menu XML if I refere to the login image like this: @android:drawable/ic_menu_login I get the following from Eclipse:

```
[2011-06-13 10:43:57 - HALASZ Mobil] W/ResourceType( 8380): Bad XML block: no root element node found
[2011-06-13 10:43:57 - HALASZ Mobil] C:\ANDROID\eclipse-SDK-3.6.2-win32\eclipse\Workspace\HALASZ Mobil\res\menu\main_opt_menu.xml:4: error: Error: Resource is not public. (at 'icon' with value '@android:drawable/ic_menu_login').
```

if I change the reference to an other icon in the standard Android.jar file, like this one: @android:drawable/ic_menu_info_details then everything works fine.

Could some one please help what am I missing? TIA.

Answer (score 3):

Easiest fix: copy the drawable from the SDK to your project.

Comment: Remember to copy the HDPI, MDPI, and LDPI versions!

Answer (score 1):

Not all of the resources in Android are publicly available (i.e. available to apps outside the OS itself). This drawable has not been declared as public, therefore you do not have access to it.

There is a workaround: Go to the [core framework source in AOSP](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=tree;f=core/res/res;hb=HEAD), copy the relevant drawables to your project (different image resolutions will be in drawables-[hml]dpi), and reference them as local drawables (i.e. @drawable/ic_menu_login).